# PHP code before HTML

Tags: php, html, security

At this moment, I'm trying to make a website with PHP and MySQLi to sell my products. Some of my PHP coding was put before the HTML tag for example my mysqli username, password for database connection. Also my email address for feedback form. When I tried to view my page source, I cant see any info of that. So my question is, is it really secure and no one will be able to see it? Or is there any way to check that? If there is a way for that, what can I do to secure my data info and prevent this from hackers. I will appreciate any explanation, code, or link to the related information.

Comment: I suggest you to start reading PHP/HTML books. But if you want just sell your products, maybe take a look on some eCommerce system: OpenCart, Magento etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as PHP and your web server are configured correctly, the PHP code is executed on the server and only the HTML output is sent to the client/browser. So, from that side, any details contained within your PHP are safe from prying eyes.

However, there are other avenues of attack that you should consider.

- Improper file permissions on your server allow other server users (including malicious programs) to read your files.
- Database servers need to be secured against outside intrusion.
- User inputs need to be sanitized.

As noted by digitalextremist in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22120153/749181), be sure that your web server is properly serving your PHP scripts and that you have a backup plan (.htaccess restriction based on file extension) in case it fails.

Be sure to have all your bases covered before declaring your code "secure."

Answer (score 3):

### Yes, it is secure; unless:

... your server ever stops handling `.php` files as server interpreted applications. In that case page loads will render as HTML only. In that situation, your sensitive information will be exposed.

*That is rare, but can happen.*

Sometimes that happens when changing or updating servers. So always be alert to make sure your web server is parsing PHP as a program and not as unparsed content.

The best way to protect against that is to `include` sources which set sense variables, and to use `.phpc` or `.inc` extensions for those files; then use `.htaccess` restrictions to *never* show those file extensions via HTTP requests.

Comment: Also, put your criticial "included" files outside of your web root. If `http://yoursite.com/index.php` becomes `/home/user/public_html/index.php`, put your critical scripts in `/home/user/includes`, not `/home/user/public_html/includes`. Just to be safe.

Answer (score 0):

> is it really secure and no one will be able to see it?

Yes.

Comment: Thanks sir. Because just before I send this post, I've been reading about PHP injection. So I'm curious about it.

Comment: I don't know why there is a need for a downvote. **+1**

Answer (score 0):

PHP code won't appear on web page. But rule number one when coding, nothing is fully secure on the Internet.

If you are a beginner and if you goal is to sell products have a look on solutions such as Prestashop, Magento (or something else).

Many plugin exist (as payment module). Moreover you will have a "better security" than an home-made development.